# SSH tunnel for 3 hops and copying files

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I've managed to do ssh tunnel just for two hops

```
ssh -L 1234:serverB:22 user@serverA

scp -P 1234 user@localhost:/file /file
```

Now I need to go from
localhost -> serverA - >serverB ->serverC

And to copy files between localhost and serverC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way:

```
ssh -L 1234:localhost:1234 user@serverA
```

Then, from serverA:

```
ssh -L 1234:serverC:22 user@serverB
```

So your local port `1234` will tunnel to `serverA`, from which it will tunnel to `serverB`, and finally to `sercerC:22`.